# how can i use 'createAttributeNS' in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I need use doucment.createAttributeNS in IE8.
I do want to know how to use.Please help me

Answer (score 1):

Use (The IE only) method `document.createNode()`

See [this blog entry](http://www.grauw.nl/blog/entry/353) and [this webpage](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/xmldom/quickref/document_createnode.html) on the method

Comment: Thank you for your help,friend! I can't invoke the document.createNode().

Answer (score 0):

You should just use `setAttributeNS` directly.

You can use it to create [namespaced attributes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace) in an XML document element.

It is not supported in IE8.

Comment: Thank you for your help,friend.In ie8,I can't use setAttributeNS.Some more ideas?